# Do the 'Smash' or 'Massacre' perks affect the Eviscerator's primary, alt and bash attacks?

Tags: killing-floor-2

The Eviscerator differs from the other Berserker melee weapons as it has no separate 'light' and 'hard' melee attacks, but a projectile and a melee attack instead.

Do the 'Smash' or 'Massacre' perks affect the Eviscerator's attacks (projectile, melee chainsaw and bash)? How do those perk skills affect those attacks?

Smash:

> Hard attacks with perk melee weapons do 50% more damage, do 25% more
>   damage on head hits, and have 200% more stumble power.

Massacre:

> Light attacks with perk melee weapons do 30% more damage and all
>   attacks with perk melee weapons are 5% faster.

Specifically I would like to know if the following apply to any of the Esciverator's attacks:

- Smash and Massacre's damage bonus
- Smash's headshot bonus damage
- Smash's stumble power bonus
- Massacre's attack speed bonus

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information provided by a Tripwire developer in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/killingfloor/comments/4y9xmr/question_interaction_between_berserker_passive/), Massacre will buff the damage of the Eviscerator's ranged attack, which is considered a light attack, while Smash will improve its headshot damage and stumble power. However, the hard attack bonus does *not* apply to the Eviscerator's melee attack, as this attack is not classified as hard *or* light.

> All perk weapon modifiers apply to the Eviscerator, even its bash, as it's considered a melee weapon.
>
> The evis has no heavy attack. The ranged projectile attack is considered a light attack, though. The bash isn't considered either light or heavy.
>
> You get all the parry bonuses on all of the Eviscerator's attack modes, as it's considered a melee weapon.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, does this mean that Massacre will give the fire rate bonus to the projectile attack? Also it is unclear to me if the alt attack (melee chainsaw) is affected by the Smash headshot or stumble power bonus as the developer seems to mention the bash attack only and says that "the evis has no heavy attack". And if Smash will give bonus headshot damage bonus to the projectile attack.

Comment: @galacticninja I did some more digging and based on a post by "simplecat" (whom everyone seems to trust) [here](http://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/forum/killing-floor-2/killing-floor-2-general/general-discussion-af/121391-question-about-zerker-perks-and-weapons), 1. Eviscerator is not benefitted from Massacre's attack speed bonus and 2. All on-perk weapon damage types are boosted by Smash's headshot damage buff.

Answer (score 0):

According to simple cat's guide: [Killing Floor 2 - Stats and Mechanics](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GDpg2mN1l_86U_RaDug0glFx8cZCuErwxZLiBKl9SyY), which contains data extracted from the game's files (Killing Floor 2 PC v1072 2018-10-18):

> Perk (Massacre): Extra damage and melee speed applied on light attacks of all melee weapons.
>
> Perk (Smash): 25% extra headshot damage applied on all on-perk weapons or on-perk damage types. 50% extra damage applied on hard attacks of all melee weapons (excluding Pulverizer's explosive attack). Stumble power multiplier applied on all on-perk weapons.

...

> Berserker's Smash skill DOES NOT affect [the Eviscerator], since
> Eviscerator's attack are neither "light" or "heavy". +25% more
> headshot damage and stumble power bonuses, however, DO work with ALL
> of Eviscerator's attacks.

As per the above info, since all of the Eviscerator's attacks are neither "light" or "heavy", massacre does *not* affect *any* of the Eviscerator's attacks, just like Smash's 50% damage bonus. However, Smash's 25% headshot damage and stumble power bonuses work with *all* of the Eviscerator's attacks. This makes Smash the obvious choice when using the Eviscerator.